# Node.js event loop blocked from express routes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an express app and one of the functionalities is "moving" files.  For example, you can drag a folder to another folder and have it's contents move.  Once all the contents are moved, the server responds accordingly.

What I've found is that when doing this with folders that contain many files (possibly additional folders), this can cause the event loop to get blocked for up to 3+ seconds, which I've found using [blocked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blocked).

Would anyone have any suggestions on how I could prevent this? One option I though is to use `child_process.fork`, I'm not sure how that will tie into an http route, but I'll test it.   Would there be any other ways to improve something like this?

Code example:  This is one part I'm testing now, that basically is building a "tree" from a materialized path pattern in Mongo:

```
var items = []
Items.find({parentId: null, user_id: '123', type: 'directory'})
  .exec(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    async.each(docs, function(doc, cb) {
      doc.getArrayTree({
        condition: {type: 'directory'}
      }, function(err, childDocs) {
        if (_.isEmpty(childDocs)) return cb();
        items.push(childDocs[0]);
        cb();
      });
    }, function(err) {
      if (err) return res.send(err);
      res.send(items);
    });
});
```

This is using mongoose materialized, specifically I believe the issue/delay is with [this](https://github.com/janez89/mongoose-materialized/blob/master/lib/materialized.js#L661).  Which is being called for every item returned.   There must be a more efficient way, perhaps with an aggregate.  This is showing about a +-500ms delay, of course this degrades as there are more documents.

Comment: If you're using async I/O, the event loop should not be blocked.  Show us the relevant code and we can advise much more specifically.

Comment: If you're doing a lot of async file I/O operations in flight at once, you might also be exhausting the internal thread pool, though that should not result in a blocked event loop.  Again, we need to see your relevant code to assess.